# AEM 6.0 SolR Enabled full text with DAM Assets

Tags: solr, aem

I'm trying to activate the indexing for document contents in the DAM using AEM 6.0.   I've already activated SolR according to the documentation, but PDFs and DOC files in the dams don't get fully indexed as they were in AEM(CQ) 5.6.1 somehow.

I'm sure I'm probably missing something very obvious but the lack of actual documentation isn't really helping.

Unless of course this is another feature that disappeared with AEM 6.0 and hasn't been reimplemented, like the spellchecker support.

This is the document I've followed
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/queries-and-indexing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems this is fixed in Oak 1.0.9, which AEM 6.0 SP2 has.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-2286

So I guess an upgrade is going to be needed.